# Creating a function for dropping the variables(categorical) from dataframe based on threshold

Tags: python, pandas

My objective is, I have a dataframe in which all columns are categorical variables. I want to remove the columns if any columns's category has exceeded the threshold/cut off.

| Var1 | Var2 | Var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | a | Lite |
| Male | b | Full |
| Male | c | Full |
| Male | c | Lite |

Here, you can see that in var1 all are Male (100% proportion) now if I pass 51% as my cut off/threshold function should give me the following:

| Var2 | Var3 |
| --- | --- |
| a | Lite |
| b | Full |
| c | Full |
| c | Lite |

```
def dist_drop(df,cut):
    vars = df.columns
    var = []
    for i in df.columns:
        val_p = df[i].value_counts(normalize = True)*100
        a = val_p.max()
        if a[i] <= cut:
            var.append = df[var]
            new_df = df[var]
       return new_df
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I guess your question contains a misunderstanding about the categorical (nominal) variable and ordinal variable! A good explanation can be found [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/what-is-the-difference-between-categorical-ordinal-and-interval-variables/)!

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar
I want to drop the columns which are having one majority class (both in nominal and in ordinal). Suppose, I have 5 categorical variables in my df and one of them is highly imbalanced like 80%, 10%, and 10% then this function drop this variable, likewise with others and give a new dataframe

Comment: @meti it should handle both nominal and ordinal because we can find the frequency distribution for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def dist_drop(df,cut):
    vars = df.columns
    var = []
    for i in df.columns:
        val_p = df[i].value_counts(normalize = True)*100
        a = val_p.max()
        if a[i] <= cut: # Condition should be just a - the max value
            var.append = df[var] # Assigning df to append instead of appending column
            new_df = df[var] # this should be after the for loop is done
       return new_df # this should be after the for loop is done
```

Made minor changes to your function. This should serve your purpose.

```
def dist_drop(df,cut):
    var = []
    for i in df.columns:
        val_p = df[i].value_counts(normalize = True)*100
        max_id = val_p.idxmax()
        max_val = val_p[max_id]
        if max_val <= cut:
            var.append(i)
    new_df = df[var]
    return new_df
```

Comment: I believe you can mention what you had changed in OPs code.

Comment: BTW I was looking for a way to group the "rare" categories in a univariate categorical variable automatically. Like if I have A, B, C, D, E in which D and E have contributions of just 0.02, and 0.01 respectively, then it would be beneficial to group them as the "other" category. Now, handpicking a threshold like <0.05 won't work for all cases. My question is if there is a way to automatically get the threshold or some kind of dynamic threshold from the given distribution to detect the "rare" categories. Please help, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `apply` to iterate over your columns and create a boolean mask. Return only columns that match your condition.

```
def dist_drop(df, cut):
    mask = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True)
                               .mul(100)
                               .le(cut)
                               .all())
    return df.loc[:, mask]
```

```
>>> dist_drop(df, 51)
  Var2  Var3
0    a  Lite
1    b  Full
2    c  Full
3    c  Lite
```

Comment: @AmitKumar if you're familiar with pandas, this is the elegant solution.

Comment: it just giving me indexes nothing else

Comment: @AmitKumar. It does not return the new dataframe with filtered columns?

Comment: BTW I was looking for a way to group the "rare" categories in a univariate categorical variable automatically. Like if I have A, B, C, D, E in which D and E have contributions of just 0.02, and 0.01 respectively, then it would be beneficial to group them as the "other" category. Now, handpicking a threshold like <0.05 won't work for all cases. My question is if there is a way to automatically get the threshold or some kind of dynamic threshold from the given distribution to detect the "rare" categories. Please help, thanks